# How to reference an object between functions that are defined in the global environment

Tags: r

I have created two functions below that are both defined in the global environment. You'll notice that `foo()` is called within `bar()` and they share the one input which is `x`. :

```
bar <- function() {
  x <- 2
  foo()
}

foo <- function(x) {
  x * 1000
}
```

`x` is not explicitly defined when `foo()` is called within `bar()`, which is causing an error with the following code:

```
bar()
```

My question is this: is there a way to define the environment where `foo()` tries to find `x`? From my research, `foo()` is looking for `x` in the global environment, but ideally it should be taking `x` from the environment of `bar()`, where `x <- 2`.

I know that the following would fix the problem, but this isn't a reasonable option in the code I'm developing. The key is getting `foo()` to reference the `x` value from the environment of `bar()`:

```
bar <- function() {
  x <- 2
  foo(x = x)
}

foo <- function(x) {
  x * 1000
}

bar()
```

Comment: You may need to specify the envir

Comment: The enclosing environment for `foo` is the global environment, hence it will look for `x` in there. You can define `foo` inside `bar`

Comment: @akrun how would I specify the environment? Would this be using eval()?

Comment: I am not sure about all the test cases for this example.  But, if you do `foo <- function() {
  x* 1000
}` should work

Comment: Removing `x` as a function argument did not work for me. I get the error `object 'x' not found`

Comment: @slava-kohut Unfortunately that's not an option since I have multiple `bar()s`, so I would prefer not to define `foo()` individually in all the separate functions.

Comment: I don't understand why passing parameters "isn't a reasonable option" in your case. What makes it different from normal R code? Perhaps you should be passing around expressions rather than functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you maybe shoudl be using expressions here for functions like `f`. Maybe

```
foo <- quote(x * 1000)
bar <- function() {
  x <- 2
  eval(foo)
}
bar()
#[1] 2000
```

Or if it does have to be a function

```
foo <- function() {
  x * 1000 
}

bar <- function() {
  x <- 2
  environment(foo)<-environment()
  foo()
}
bar()
#[1] 2000
```

Note that this doesn't permanently change `foo`, it just makes a local copy of `foo` in `bar` with a different enclosing environment.

The latter solution is much like my solution for the previous question: [R specify function environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279076/r-specify-function-environment/49619767#49619767)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you something akin to what you want. The trick is to use a closure to define the function(/environment) you want, and then use the double left arrow assign to assign the value of x within `bar`. Double left arrow assign gives you the ability to write to a variable in the parent environment.

```r
make_foo_bar_pair = function() {
  # Define the shared state...
  x <- 0

  # Make your bar function
  bar <- function() {
    x <<- 2 # Use the double left arrow assign to modify the shared state
    foo()
  }
  
  # Make your foo function
  foo <- function() {
    x * 1000 # Which references the shared state
  }
  
  # Return your linked functions...
  list(foo, bar)
}

# Make a pair of functions with shared state...
pair = make_foo_bar_pair()
foo = pair[[1]]
bar = pair[[2]]

# Call them
foo() # 0 (foo uses the initial value of x that it closed over)
bar() # 2000
foo() # 2000
```

Each `foo`/`bar` pair that you create will reference a different `x`, so calling `make_foo_bar_pair` repeatedly will give you fresh `foo`/`bar` functions sharing a distinct `x`.

If you really need to use the global environment you could do this...

```r
# Make your bar function
bar <- function() {
  x <<- 2 # Use the double left arrow assign to modify the shared state
  foo()
}
  
# Make your foo function
foo <- function() {
  x * 1000 # Which references the shared state
}
```

...but doing things in the global environment like that feels like a code smell.