# Assigning parents in R using eval() function

Tags: r, dynamic-scope

I am trying to create a decorator in R that when used inside of another function will use the calling environment of that function as parent. I believe this can be achieved using eval() but I am having difficulties with the implementation.

This is what I got so far:

```
library(rlang)

###Decorator definition
dynamicCall <- function(decorated) {

  dynamicEnv <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())
  
  attach(dynamicEnv)
  
  eval(decorated, enclos = dynamicEnv)
  
  print('parents in dynamicCall')
  print(env_parents(dynamicEnv))
}



###Function to be decorated
f <- function() {
  print('parents in f')
  print(env_parents(environment()))
}


###Function to be called in
g <- function() {
  print('calling environment')
  print(environment())
  dynamicCall(f())
}

g()
```

And this is the output:

```
[1] "calling environment"
<environment: 0x00000211a91ff840>
[1] "parents in f"
[[1]] $ <env: global>
[1] "parents in dynamicCall"
[[1]]   <env: 0x00000211a91ff840>
[[2]] $ <env: global>
```

I don't understand why "parents in f" is different than "parents in dynamicCall". The enclosing environment should be *dynamicEnv* so the parents list should be the same? I'll be grateful for any help!

edit: adding the library

Comment: Your code does not run.  Maybe you are using some package but the library call is missing.  f is defined in the global environment so calling parent.env(environment()) from within it gives the global environment whereas DynamicEnv is defined to have the caller of DynamicCall, i.e. the active environment when g runs, as its parent environment.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the beggining of the code with library(rlang). Regarding your response: 

f is ran with eval(decorated, enclos = dynamicEnv), so I would expect it to have DynamicEnv as the parent environment. Is that not what 'enclos=' does? Documentation suggests that.

Comment: Running f in a different environment does not change its environment.  The environment of a function is part of the function definition and you would have to change f itself, i.e. environment(f) <- e where e is some environment.  Note that if f depends on objects in its original environment the new function may no longer run properly.

Comment: Suggest you compare running parent.env(environment()) and parent.frame() within your functions. and also look at environment(f),, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try a different way to do this then!

Comment: Maybe this existing question is what you are trying to get at? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279076/r-specify-function-environment